# PHP: Don't echo a variable in a while loop IF it's a duplicate

Tags: php, server-side, server-side-scripting

I have a variable in an SQL query-based while loop. e.g:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    echo $row['row'];

}
```

The while loop is functional and works, however the variable contains duplicate strings.

**How do I prevent duplicate row variables echoing in my while loop with PHP?**

Note: This is a PHP question, not an SQL question.

Comment: It depends.  Is the data ordered a particular way, i.e. are all of the duplicates together in the record set?

Comment: This *is* an SQL question.  Only select the data you want in the first place.  Leave sorting out duplicates up to your database, where it can be handled efficiently.

Comment: No they are scattered completely randomly

Comment: Assume SQL is impossible

Comment: Why would SQL be impossible?

Comment: That's not the question, the question is "Is it possible in PHP, and if so, how?"

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep track of each row's unique ID. If you see again, skip it.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$ids = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if (!isset($ids[$row['id']])) {
        continue;
    }
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
    echo $row['row'];

}
```

FYI, this is a lot easier and faster if you do it in SQL. But if you *must* do it in PHP this is how you would do it.

Comment: far better to just use the `row[id]` as the key, saving the in_array repetitive searching. `if (!isset($ids[$row['id']]))`

Comment: Is this possible when handling string variables? i.e not using their ID, but instead preventing duplication of the actual echoed variable

Comment: @zak You can use any value as long as it is unique.